# Angular build errors

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, npm

Please tell me what's going on. 
I encounter the following error when building my project. Already tried to delete typings, angular,, directory and then do typings install with no change.
All of the packages to which he swears, installed. Get the following error:

```
app/app.module.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'NgModule'.
    app/app.module.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/index"' has no exported member 'BrowserModule'.
    app/app.module.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'RouterModule'.
    app/app.module.ts(10,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module './app.routes'.
    app/app.route.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'Routes'.
    app/main.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index"' has no exported member 'platformBrowserDynamic'.
    app/main.ts(3,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module './app/app.module'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flexbox/_module.d.ts(10,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'ModuleWithProviders'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flexbox/api/base-adapter.d.ts(8,22): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flexbox/api/base.d.ts(8,22): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/media-query/breakpoints/break-points-provider.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InjectionToken'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/media-query/breakpoints/break-points-token.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InjectionToken'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/media-query/media-monitor-provider.d.ts(21,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Optional'.
    node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/media-query/observable-media-provider.d.ts(23,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Optional'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/button-toggle/button-toggle.d.ts(8,22): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/button/button.d.ts(8,33): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/checkbox/checkbox.d.ts(8,81): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/chips/chip.d.ts(8,47): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/a11y/live-announcer.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InjectionToken'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/a11y/live-announcer.d.ts(29,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Optional'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/line/line.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/overlay/overlay-container.d.ts(36,11): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Optional'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts(8,78): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/overlay/position/viewport-ruler.d.ts(34,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Optional'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/overlay/scroll/scroll-dispatcher.d.ts(64,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Optional'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/ripple/ripple.d.ts(8,67): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InjectionToken'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/style/focus-origin-monitor.d.ts(8,65): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/style/focus-origin-monitor.d.ts(102,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Optional'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/datepicker/datepicker-input.d.ts(8,65): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/datepicker/datepicker-input.d.ts(10,49): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/forms/index"' has no exported member 'ValidationErrors'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/dialog/dialog-container.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/animations'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/dialog/dialog-injector.d.ts(8,20): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InjectionToken'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/grid-list/grid-list.d.ts(8,50): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/grid-list/grid-tile.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/icon/icon-registry.d.ts(9,27): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/index"' has no exported member 'DomSanitizer'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/menu/menu-animations.d.ts(8,42): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/animations'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/progress-spinner/progress-spinner.d.ts(8,41): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/radio/radio.d.ts(8,59): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/select/select-animations.d.ts(8,42): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/animations'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slide-toggle/slide-toggle.d.ts(8,84): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slider/slider.d.ts(8,47): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/snack-bar/snack-bar-container.d.ts(8,43): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/snack-bar/snack-bar-container.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/animations'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/ink-bar.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/nikita/django-ng2-starter/ngApp/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/tab-body.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/animations'.
    node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tooltip/tooltip.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/animations'.
    node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(181,15): error TS2428: All declarations of 'ObjectContaining' must have identical type parameters.
    node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(212,10): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'CustomEqualityTester'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(70,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'main' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'NodeModule'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(81,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'parent' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'NodeModule'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(82,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'children' must be of type 'any[]', but here has type 'NodeModule[]'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(102,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'BufferEncoding'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(378,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'stdout' must be of type 'WritableStream', but here has type 'WriteStream'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(430,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'platform' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'Platform'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(588,26): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Buffer'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(588,50): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'SlowBuffer'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(632,5): error TS2309: An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(777,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Agent'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(832,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'addressType' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'number | "udp4" | "udp6"'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(835,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Worker'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(1316,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'SNICallback' must be of type '(servername: string) => any', but here has type '(servername: string, cb: (err: Error, ctx: SecureContext) => any) => any'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(1518,17): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'CompleterResult'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(1555,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Script'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2880,16): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'StringDecoder' must be of type 'new (encoding: string) => NodeStringDecoder', but here has type 'new (encoding?: string) => NodeStringDecoder'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2931,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'TLSSocket'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3128,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'pfx' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string | Buffer[]'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3155,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'key' must be of type 'string | Buffer', but here has type 'string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3157,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'cert' must be of type 'string | Buffer', but here has type 'string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3158,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'ca' must be of type '(string | Buffer)[]', but here has type 'string | Buffer | (string | Buffer)[]'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3397,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'padding' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'number'.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3642,5): error TS2309: An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.
    node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3719,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
    node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts(9,22): error TS2415: Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'.
      Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
        Type '<T, R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>' is not assignable to type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<R>'.
          Type 'Observable<T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<R>'.
            Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.
    node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts(45,11): error TS2428: All declarations of 'WeakMap' must have identical type parameters.
    node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts(21,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
    node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts(157,11): error TS2428: All declarations of 'WeakMap' must have identical type parameters.
    node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.symbol.wellknown.d.ts(133,11): error TS2428: All declarations of 'WeakMap' must have identical type parameters.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(3,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(40,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'name' must have identical modifiers.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(100,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '[Symbol.unscopables]' must be of type '{ copyWithin: boolean; entries: boolean; fill: boolean; find: boolean; findIndex: boolean; keys: ...', but here has type 'any'.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(217,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'flags' must have identical modifiers.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(231,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'EPSILON' must have identical modifiers.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(266,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER' must have identical modifiers.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(273,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER' must have identical modifiers.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(412,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must be of type '"Symbol"', but here has type 'string'.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(412,5): error TS2687: All declarations of '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must have identical modifiers.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(419,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(600,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'size' must have identical modifiers.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(606,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(611,11): error TS2428: All declarations of 'WeakMap' must have identical type parameters.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(619,27): error TS2344: Type 'K' does not satisfy the constraint 'object'.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(620,53): error TS2344: Type 'K' does not satisfy the constraint 'object'.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(621,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'prototype' must be of type 'WeakMap<object, any>', but here has type 'WeakMap<any, any>'.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(621,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(635,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'prototype' must be of type 'WeakSet<object>', but here has type 'WeakSet<any>'.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(635,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
    typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(647,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'value' must have identical modifiers.
    typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts(84,15): error TS2428: All declarations of 'ObjectContaining' must have identical type parameters.
    typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts(114,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'CustomEqualityTester'.
    typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts(123,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'CustomMatcherFactory'.
    typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts(128,9): error TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.
    typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts(151,24): error TS2314: Generic type 'Matchers<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
    typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts(274,15): error TS2428: All declarations of 'Matchers' must have identical type parameters.
    typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts(279,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'actual' must be of type 'T', but here has type 'any'.
    typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts(303,14): error TS2314: Generic type 'Matchers<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
    typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts(339,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'SpecFunction'.
    typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts(360,24): error TS2314: Generic type 'Matchers<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
    typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts(372,30): error TS2314: Generic type 'Matchers<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(78,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'BufferEncoding'.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(503,9): error TS2502: 'BuffType' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(504,9): error TS2502: 'SlowBuffType' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(505,26): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Buffer'.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(567,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
      Named property 'addListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(567,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
      Named property 'emit' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(567,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
      Named property 'prependOnceListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(567,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
      Named property 'removeListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(578,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
      Named property 'addListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(578,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
      Named property 'emit' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(578,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
      Named property 'once' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(578,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
      Named property 'prependListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(578,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
      Named property 'prependOnceListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(578,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
      Named property 'removeListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(606,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
      Named property 'addListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(606,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
      Named property 'emit' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(606,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
      Named property 'on' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(606,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
      Named property 'once' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(606,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
      Named property 'prependListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(606,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(632,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
      Named property 'on' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(632,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
      Named property 'once' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(632,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
      Named property 'prependListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(632,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
      Named property 'prependOnceListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(632,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
      Named property 'removeListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(682,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Agent'.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(727,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Worker'.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(980,22): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'CompleterResult'.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(1020,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Script'.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(1247,22): error TS2430: Interface 'Socket' incorrectly extends interface 'Duplex'.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(1247,22): error TS2430: Interface 'Socket' incorrectly extends interface 'Duplex'.
      Types of property 'pause' are incompatible.
        Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '() => this'.
          Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'this'.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(1298,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Socket' and 'EventEmitter'.
      Named property 'removeListener' of types 'Socket' and 'EventEmitter' are not identical.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(1861,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'TLSSocket'.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(2159,18): error TS2420: Class 'Readable' incorrectly implements interface 'ReadableStream'.
      Types of property 'pause' are incompatible.
        Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '{ (): void; (): this; }'.
          Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'this'.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(2196,18): error TS2420: Class 'Duplex' incorrectly implements interface 'ReadWriteStream'.
      Types of property 'pause' are incompatible.
        Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '{ (): void; (): this; }'.
          Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'this'.
    typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(2210,18): error TS2420: Class 'Transform' incorrectly implements interface 'ReadWriteStream'.
      Types of property 'pause' are incompatible.
        Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '{ (): void; (): this; }'.
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/q": "^1.0.1",
    "angular": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-animate": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-aria": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "material": "^0.1.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "typescript": "^2.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.53",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.78",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Comment: Well, what do you expect when you're mixing both AngularJS 1.x.x and Angular?

Comment: What version of npm do you have?

Comment: @Edric But I did not use them, I accidentally installed them

Comment: I deleted the node_modules folder and installed it again - everything works.
As a result, took another starting project, with this in the future there were problems.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your npm install was broken. Delete the node_modules directory and run npm install again.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is due to a compilation bug in Typescript 2.4 (see [Typescript 2.4 RxJS bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16593))

The solution is to change `"typescript": "^2.4.1"` to `"typescript": "2.3.4"` in your `package.json` file and rebuild your project.

I had a similar error in an Ionic Project and this fix worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. After changing my typescript error from ***"typescript": "^2.4.1"*** to ***"typescript": "2.2.1"***, the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have quite a few things going on, firstly there's a known issue with rxjs and the latest typescript version (2.4.1 should work, so pin you package.json to that or do  [what I suggest in the issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17800#issuecomment-311675622)).

Also, make sure `@types/node` matches the version of node you are running. `npm install --save-dev @types/node` should update it.

Some of those errors could be because of incompatible packages being brought together. I suggest destroying your package.json, package-lock.json, and node_modules folder and then incrementally `npm install`ing only what your application needs to grab the latest versions of them. (and do the linked fix for rxjs + typescript 2.4.x)